# Deploying SQL Server Databases for clients

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, web-deployment

I have the following script which creates a new database, a new user and login.  I have some custom software that my clients use to log into the database and create the necessary tables, SP and populate the tables with data.  The databases are hosted remotely online which I have full access to.

****EDIT-> The problem I have is that I cannot open a new connection and create any tables using the new user.  Its looks like a permissions issue as it works ok with sa root account login.**

Ideally I would like run this single script so I can deploy a new database to a new client via SQL Server Management Studio easily with the minimal of fuss

Please see my script below:

```
-- SEARCH AND REPLACE THE FOLLOWING TERMS
--
-- db_TestDatabase          Database name
-- TestPa$$w0rd           password
-- TestUser1                username

use master
go

--create a test database
CREATE DATABASE [db_TestDatabase]
GO

--create user login
CREATE LOGIN [TestUser1] WITH PASSWORD=N'TestPa$$w0rd'
GO
--create user in database
CREATE USER [TestUser1] FOR LOGIN [TestUser1] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[test_Schema]
GO
--create role
CREATE ROLE [test_Role] AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
GO
--create schema
CREATE SCHEMA [test_Schema] AUTHORIZATION [TestUser1]
GO
--apply permissions to schemas
GRANT ALTER ON SCHEMA::[test_Schema] TO [test_Role]
GO
GRANT CONTROL ON SCHEMA::[test_Schema] TO [test_Role]
GO
GRANT SELECT ON SCHEMA::[test_Schema] TO [test_Role]
GO
GRANT DELETE ON SCHEMA::[dbo] TO [test_Role]
GO
GRANT INSERT ON SCHEMA::[dbo] TO [test_Role]
GO
GRANT SELECT ON SCHEMA::[dbo] TO [test_Role]
GO
GRANT UPDATE ON SCHEMA::[dbo] TO [test_Role]
GO
GRANT REFERENCES ON SCHEMA::[dbo] TO [test_Role]
GO
--ensure role membership is correct
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'test_Role ', N'TestUser1'
GO
--allow users to create tables in test_Schema
GRANT CREATE TABLE TO [test_Role]
GO
--Allow user to connect to database
GRANT CONNECT TO [TestUser1]
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Are you saying you **can't** use the `sa` login, or you **can**?  You haven't clearly described what the problem actually is.  Perhaps an error message would help.

Comment: sa works fine, the new user created in the script does not work.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a User Access Control issue, try right clicking Management Studio and **Run as Administrator**, if you have that privilege and it may get past the issue you're seeing.

Some related reading:

[**User Account Control and SQL Server**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc512639.aspx)

> User Account Control affects Microsoft SQL Server in terms of
>   connectivity (SQL Server login) and in limiting access to resources on
>   the administrators’ access control list (ACL).
>
> In versions earlier than Windows Vista and Windows Server 2008,
>   members of the local administrator group do not need their own SQL
>   Server logins and they do not need to be granted administrator
>   privileges inside SQL Server. They connect to SQL Server as the
>   built-in server principal BUILTIN\Administrators (B\A), and they have
>   administrator privileges because B\A is a member of the sysadmin fixed
>   server role. Administrator rights are stripped away in Windows Vista
>   and Windows Server 2008, so administrator users cannot connect to SQL
>   Server instance by virtue of being B\A, unless connecting from an
>   elevated client application.

Comment: The user created uses "SQL Server Authentication" which is just a username and password and I am not using Windows Authentication?